# XAMPP - change IP Address

Tags: php, xampp, codeigniter-3, ip-address

So I have a smart phone and a windows 10 connected under the same Wi-Fi network. The Windows 10 has `IP Address` of ex. `192.168.1.2` and a `Rest API` `http://192.168.1.2/Codeigniter/RestFullAPI/menu/view`

What I want is to change the `192.168.1.2` into a something else like myName.com.

I want to change it because sometimes the `IP Address` changes and it would be troublesome because I am making an Android APP that views the list of menus.

Comment: set it static to the machine in your router, changes hosts file wont help if the IP changes.

Comment: do I have to manually configure the IP of windows 10 or I'll do it on my router?

Comment: Does your router support local DNS? ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/311877/why-do-most-routers-not-include-local-dns)).  Otherwise use whatever the equivalent of a hosts file is for your particular mobile OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can Change ServerName in httpd.Config  in Apache, Also you can turn off firewall or open specific port for Wi-fi access.